# ListBox within userform is not showing full row of values

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I've made a Userform [Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCPV8.png) which I am using to filter a set of data and come back with choices fitting those choices.  The filtering works; however when I add the filtered table to a listbox (SelectHousingList) it cuts off the last columns.  The code below shows that I've set the listbox to have 10 columns and it has a horozontal scroll as well.

```
Private Sub AttenuationList_Click()
SelectedAttenuationText.Value = AttenuationList.Text
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("J3").Value = SelectedAttenuationText.Value

End Sub

Private Sub CatalystDiameterList_Click()
SelectedCatalystDiameterText.Value = CatalystDiameterList.Text
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("H3").Value = SelectedCatalystDiameterText.Value

End Sub

Private Sub ConfigurationList_Click()
SelectedConfigurationText.Value = ConfigurationList.Text
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("L3").Value = SelectedConfigurationText.Value

End Sub

Private Sub FilterButton_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet2

SelectHousingList.Clear

Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B3")
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("H3")
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("J3")
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("L3")

Set Rng = Worksheets("FSC PSC 
PFC").Range("B5:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
With SelectHousingList
.ColumnCount = 10
For Each Cel1 In Rng
.AddItem CStr(Cel1.Value)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cel1.Offset(0, 1).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cel1.Offset(0, 2).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cel1.Offset(0, 3).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cel1.Offset(0, 4).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cel1.Offset(0, 5).Value
Next Cel1
End With

End Sub

Private Sub HousingTypeList_Click()
SelectedHousingText.Value = HousingTypeList.Text
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B3").Value =     
SelectedHousingText.Value

CatalystDiameterList.Clear

lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

curVal = Me.HousingTypeList.Value

For x = 6 To lastrow
If Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Cells(x, "B") = curVal Then
Me.CatalystDiameterList.AddItem Worksheets("FSC PSC         
PFC").Cells(x, "H")
End If
Next x


End Sub

Private Sub MaterialList_Click()
SelectedMaterialText.Value = MaterialList.Text
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("D4").Value =         
SelectedMaterialText.Value

End Sub

Private Sub ResetButton_Click()

SelectHousingList.Clear
CatalystDiameterList.Clear
SelectedCatalystDiameterText = ""


On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Private Sub SelectHousingList_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        'ADDING DIFFERENT HOUSING STYLES TO CHOOSE FROM
HousingTypeList.AddItem "(FSC) Catalyst Housing"
HousingTypeList.AddItem "(PFC) Catalyst Housing"
HousingTypeList.AddItem "(PSC) Catalyst Housing"

        'ADDING DIFFERENT ATTENUATION GRADES TO CHOOSE
AttenuationList.AddItem "Critical"
AttenuationList.AddItem "Hospital"
AttenuationList.AddItem "Converter Only"

        'ADDING DIFFERENT CONFIGURATIONS TO CHOOSE
ConfigurationList.AddItem "EIEO"
ConfigurationList.AddItem "EISO"
ConfigurationList.AddItem "SIEO"
ConfigurationList.AddItem "SISO"

        'ADDING DIFFERENT MATERIALS TO CHOOSE
MaterialList.AddItem "CS/CS"
MaterialList.AddItem "SS/CS"
MaterialList.AddItem "SS/SS"

End Sub
```

Any/All help appreciated.

Comment: As far as i know, there is a 10 column limit on listbox (it's from 0-9)

Comment: I just switched the code to 9 columns, along with the properties of the listbox but it is still only showing 5 columns.  

thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I had a mistake in my FilterButton code where I was only adding 5 values to the listobx after the filter button was clicked.  My mistake, but it is still only able to have 9 columns within the listbox as mentioned in the comments.

```
Private Sub FilterButton_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet2

SelectHousingList.Clear

Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B3")
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("H3")
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("J3")
Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B6:Z10000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("L3")

Set Rng = Worksheets("FSC PSC PFC").Range("B5:B1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 With SelectHousingList
 .ColumnCount = 14
 For Each Cel1 In Rng
.AddItem CStr(Cel1.Value)
**.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cel1.Offset(0, 1).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cel1.Offset(0, 2).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cel1.Offset(0, 3).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cel1.Offset(0, 4).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cel1.Offset(0, 5).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = Cel1.Offset(0, 6).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 7) = Cel1.Offset(0, 7).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 8) = Cel1.Offset(0, 8).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 9) = Cel1.Offset(0, 9).Value**

Next Cel1
 End With

End Sub
```

Sorry for the inconvenience, just took a different look at it to see it.

Thanks all!